# Find the largest prime factor.

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Is there a method to find the largest prime factor of $2^{2024} + 2^{2023} + 2^{2022} + 2^{2021}$?

Like I know that's the same as $15 * 2^{2021}$ but where do I go from here?

Comment: You're probably overthinking it. The prime factorization is clearly
$$
2^{2021} \cdot 3 \cdot 5
$$
What could the prime factors even be, other than $2,3,$ or $5$?

Comment: Thank you, I'm so sleep deprived. And yes I was overthinking it.